# List of deleted records

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

i have a grid of (agents) in oracle apex with the button DELETE , and i want to know  THE STEPS  how to show deleted rows in another grid
if its not possible what if instead of deleting the row from the table (agents), moving it to another table (agents_deleted)
is that possible ?

Comment: Deleted records are deleted. You cannot show them anywhere. You can move with [INSERT](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/insert.php) followed by [DELETE](https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/delete.php).

Comment: what if instead of deleting the row from the table (agents), moving it to another table (agents_deleted) is that possible ?

Comment: Yes, INSERT the records to be deleted into another table, then delete them. See the links I provided.

Comment: thanks, i appreciate your help

Comment: You can do "soft delete" -  add a hidden column `deleted`. And instead of actually deleting records, mark them as deleted. This way you can see `where deleted = 1` to see deleted rows. Otherwise, use `where deleted = 0`

Comment: thanks T.S for your help, im new whith oracle apex , can you please show me the steps to do so

Answer (score 0):

You can create another table audit_agent and make use of trigger to insert records in audit table after a delete(or even update or insert).